# Calculation of runs after the umpire decision gets reviewed

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, wicket

During the last match between [Sri Lanka and South Africa](http://www.espncricinfo.com/sri-lanka-v-south-africa-2014/engine/match/730085.html). Jayawardane was given out as LBW and the ball went for boundary after got hit the pads. The batsman reviewed it. The decision was reversed, but no runs added to the total.

A question arose on seeing the above thing,

A team batting second need 4 runs to win in one ball. The batsman was given LBW in that delivery and the ball went for four, since the fielders started celebrating the victory without concentrating the ball. The decision was reviewed and reversed.

Who will win the match at this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [ICC playing conditions of Umpire reviewing system](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/362178.html), still the bowling team will win the match.

> If following a review request, an original decision of 'Out' is
>   changed to 'Not Out', then the ball is still deemed to have become
>   dead when the original decision was made (as per [Law 23.1(a)(iii)](http://www.rulesofcricket.co.uk/the_rules_of_cricket/the_rules_of_cricket_law_23.htm)).

The only benefit that the batting team can gain is the batsman's wicket. But, there is a chance for them, if the ball was given crease no-ball in the review, they will get one run and an extra ball to chase the target.

Comment: (iii) says "when a batsman is dismissed". In the case of an lbw dismissal (whether overturned or not), is the ball retrospectively deemed to have become dead when the ball struck the pad, or not until the umpire raises the finger? Obviously if you run one or the ball reaches the boundary between those two events then the runs don't count, I'm just wondering is that because the ball was dead all along, or because they explicitly don't count?

Comment: @SteveJessop, the ball will become dead immedietely after the umpire rises his finger.

Comment: So in the event that the umpire did take time to think about the lbw, and the ball reached the boundary before it was dead (thereby becoming dead), then in that subset of the case considered by the question could the runs be awarded? As a kind of converse, if the umpire is really quick to raise the finger (thereby making the ball dead), *then* a fielder catches it, then review reviews a nick, is he out or does the catch not count because the ball was dead?

Comment: @SteveJessop, yes the catch will not be counted since the ball was already dead. But, this is rare very rare in real cricket.

Comment: @SportsFan: sure, and the umpire can always choose to avoid any risk of it, by delaying the decision until the ball comes down ;-) As for the boundary, I guess we'll have to wait until it happens before there's any serious discussion whether the laws should award runs following an overturned dismissal. It doesn't have to be last ball even, if a team needing 6 off two balls had this happen to them, thus needing 6 off the final ball instead of 2, it might raise a ruckus. Especially should they score 4 off a yorker.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the player would have been out the ball is deemed to have been dead.  So in the case of an umpire taking a long time to make an LBW decision as soon as it is given out the ball is deemed to be dead from the moment it hit the pad.